# Page appears different in each browser, I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so im trying to make my nav bar close when the link is clicked. the links when clicked are directed to a section not to a new page. the nav bar when its on a large screen i want it to still show but when its on small screen i want that the burger menu will automatically be close when for example the nextevent link is pressed any ideas?

```
<body>
        <nav>
        <header class="header d-flex align-items-center container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-center flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <div class="logo">
                  <h4>thomas<br> venutu</h4>
                </div>
        </div>
            <ul class="nav-links ">
                <li><a href="#section2">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#section2">NextEvent</a> </li>
                <li><a href="index">Music </a> </li>
                <li><a href="index">About</a> </li>
                <li><a href="index">Boooking</a> </li>

            </ul>

            <div class="burger">
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </header>
        </nav>
```

```
#

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#extra space{

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section2 {

        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5em 0 5em 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-size: 125% auto;
    }



#section2 header {
            margin: 0 0 2em 0;
        }


    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  min-height: 12vh;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}

.logo{
    color:whitesmoke;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size:22px;
}

.nav-links{
    display:flex!important;
    justify-content: space-around!important;
    width: 100%!important;


}
.nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    margin:3px;
}
.burger{
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links a{
color:whitesmoke;
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 3px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .nav-links{
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 60%;


}

}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    body{
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
    .nav{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    .nav-links{
        font-size: 1px;
        position:fixed;
        right:0px;
        height:92vh;
        top: 0px;
        background-color: #0c0c0c;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-disable{
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .nav-links li{
        ;

    }

    .burger{
        display: block;
         position: absolute;
         top: 8px;
         right: 16px;

    }

    .nav-active{
    transform: translateX(30%);
    }
    #section2 {
    background-image:url("background image venuto4.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width:100% ;
    background-color: black;

}
    #getting-started{
        font-size:12px;
    }

    #day{
        font-size:14px;
    }
    #minutes{
        font-size:14px;
    }
    #hours{
        font-size:12px;
    }
}
#section1 {
    background-image: url("background6.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:black;


}
#section2 {
    background-image:url("background image venuto4.jpg");
    background-image:no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width:100% ;
    background-color: black;

}
#section3 {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
}
#section4 {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 700px;

}
#section5 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 700px;
}
.btn-info{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.card-img-top{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px;
}
h1{color: #3b3e42;

}
```

js

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');


    });

    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s`;
        console.log(index / 7);
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-disable');
    });

    navLinks.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');


    });



}
navSlide();
```

need fix

```
navLinks.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');


    });
```

Comment: Firstly, forget the DreamWeaver browser. It's not as reliable indicator of anything. Never use it. Secondly, which version of IE? The problem is most likely due to an incompatible CSS or JS method you're using.

Comment: _“the code got no errors”_ - no true. Fix what https://validator.w3.org/ lists as errors first of all.

Comment: Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

Comment: Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363 and @cbroe i cant understand what you mean

Comment: the code shows no error in browser console and even in the dream weaver

Comment: Dreamweaver is not the authority on this. Your HTML code still contains errors, and the validator shows you what they are.

Comment: how can i make the css and js compatible to any browser?

Comment: Edge is not the same as IE. I've edited your question as such

Comment: yes i know and im sorry

Comment: buth both show the same error

Comment: and @cbroe your link is only showing blank page,,,

Comment: @cbroe i fixed the errors using another validator but still shows the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet explorer may skip media query so to prevent that follow conventional method. Also order of media query also matters.

There are multiple reason would be there.

Try removing

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
}
```

And all code inside this move to top.

So it will be

```
//for all, including desktop and mobile goes here
html{...

// for less mobile/smartphone and ipad vertical
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
}

// for all mobile/smartphone devices
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
}
...
```